# Compare XML documents in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am novice to C#, I am looking to compare XML files and get third output.
I have read its possible using 'xmldiff' class.
I could also find below, however I am not sure which C# project type should be used?
Kindly help me to understand which project type shall I select?

I tried with Class library but it gives me error at `(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |                                        XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces | XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes)`

Also I dont see the below asking for file location to save.

```
private void CompareXml(string file1, string file2, string diffFileNameWithPath)
{
    //file1 = "XMLDelta_A.xml";
    //file2 = "XMLDelta_B.xml";

    XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(@"\\msi-ws60-a0080\Parisa\wetransfer-6f37e5\XML\XMLDelta_A.xml");
    XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(@"\\msi-ws60-a0080\Parisa\wetransfer-6f37e5\XML\XMLDelta_B.xml");

    StringBuilder differenceStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(diffFileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlWriter diffGramWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fs);

        XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
                                XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                                XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
        bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(file1, file2, false, diffGramWriter);

        diffGramWriter.Close();
    }
```

[image]

Now it says below

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning NU1701 Package 'XMLDiffPatch 1.0.8.28' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I installed the Xmldiff so the errors are reduced.
Now I am getting error at private void CompareXml(string file1,
                                string file2,
                                string diffFileNameWithPath)

 A namespace cannot contain method.

Comment: Please show the exact error message

Comment: Your method must be part of a class. In the picture you posted, it is outside of the class.

Comment: can you please guide me where should it be, I am novice.

Comment: Move the } that is before the method to behind the method. But frankly, this is not the kind of questions to be asked here. Better start with some basic C# tutorial.

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverFlow, @MithilKapre !** Can you provide the error message? If the above code isn't working, the program should crash and/or display an error message. If you can, could you post it here? Thanks :)

Comment: sorry that works but now it says below

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning NU1701 Package 'XMLDiffPatch 1.0.8.28' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Does the code work?  It appears the code was built with a different version of VS and was upgraded to latest version of Net.  But Microsoft is legally saying the upgrade may not work.  The code may still run properly.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019. Could you get it running? I can't make it work

Answer (score 0):

Manage to resolve it some arguments were incorrect. Thanks for your help.I used below

XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"\msi-ws60-a0080\Parisa\wetransfer-6f37e5\XML\XMLDelta_A.xml"));
            XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"\msi-ws60-a0080\Parisa\wetransfer-6f37e5\XML\XMLDelta_B.xml"));

```
        //StringBuilder differenceStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       // using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(diffFileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlWriter diffGramWriter = new XmlTextWriter("diffgram.xml", new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding());
            //XmlWriter.Create(fs);

            XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
                                    XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                                    XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
            bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, false, diffGramWriter);
            diffGramWriter.Flush();
            diffGramWriter.Close();
            //fs.Close();
```